# SQL query for getting count for grouped items

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a table with the following columns:

```
agent     status  

A          Mail Sent  
B          Fax Sent  
A          Fax Sent  
B          Mail Sent  
B          Mail Sent  
B          Fax Sent
```

I want to get this result:

```
Agent  Fax_Count    Mail_Count

A      1            1  
B      2            2
```

Answer (score 7):

You can try something like this

```
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE(
    agent VARCHAR(10),
    status VARCHAR(10)
)

INSERT INTO @TABLE (agent,status) SELECT 'A','Mail Sent'
INSERT INTO @TABLE (agent,status) SELECT 'B','Fax Sent'
INSERT INTO @TABLE (agent,status) SELECT 'A','Fax Sent'
INSERT INTO @TABLE (agent,status) SELECT 'B','Mail Sent'
INSERT INTO @TABLE (agent,status) SELECT 'B','Mail Sent'
INSERT INTO @TABLE (agent,status) SELECT 'B','Fax Sent' 

SELECT  agent,
        SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'Mail Sent' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Mail_Count ,
        SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'Fax Sent' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Fax_Count
FROM    @TABLE
GROUP BY agent
```

Comment: Like this answer (better than that I was typing). The base design of the table is not very smooth to me (it doesn't seem to have a primary key, is denormalized as hell), and should probably be changed.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to astander's (good) solution:

```
SELECT  agent,
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM myTable WHERE agent = t.agent AND status = 'Mail Sent') Mail_Count,
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM myTable WHERE agent = t.agent AND status = 'Fax Sent') Fax_Count
FROM    myTable t
GROUP BY agent
```

Depending on the distribution of your data, performance might be better than his solution (no SUM over a calculated field) or worse (sub-selects) or equal (if the query analyzer finds the optimal execution plan in both cases).

Comment: Thanks. :-) However, although I'm glad about the upvote, I should clarify that astander's solution does not *need* a temp table; he just uses it to recreate the original table of the question and illustrate his solution.

Comment: Good point which I observed previously, but I have found for REALLY new SQL developers, this might be confusing, not a huge thing either way.

Answer (score 0):

```
  select Name, SUM(MailSent),SUM(FaxSent)
  from 
  (
  select 
   case Status when 'Mail Sent' then 1 else 0 end as MailSent , 
   case Status when 'Fax Sent' then 1 else 0 end as FaxSent  ,
   Name
   from Agents
  ) tmp
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this... probably not the most graceful but it would work...
Just swap out @Table with the table you're querying...

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  T.AGENT,
  (SELECT COUNT(AGENT) FROM @TABLE WHERE AGENT = T.AGENT AND Status LIKE 'Fax%') AS Fax_Count,
  (SELECT COUNT(AGENT) FROM @TABLE WHERE AGENT = T.AGENT AND Status LIKE 'Mail%') AS Email_Count
FROM
  @TABLE T
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the new way (since SQL Server 2005) to solve the problem by using [PIVOT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(SQL.90).aspx) functionality:

```
SELECT agent, [Mail Sent] AS Mail_Count, [Fax Sent] AS Fax_Count
FROM 
(
  SELECT T.agent, T.status, COUNT(*) AS Counter
  FROM tblAgents AS T
  GROUP BY T.agent, T.status
) AS Data
PIVOT
(
  SUM(Counter) FOR [status] IN ([Mail Sent], [Fax Sent])
) AS PivotTable
```

I do not use this my self very often due to more complex syntax, but perhaps there is some performance to gain?